# Move Azure SQL Managed Instance across subscription

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have two SQL managed instance in two different region(One in Australia East another one in Australia Southeast. They are in a Pay-As-You-Go subscription. Now I want to move those resources to a CSP subscription. Is it possible to move SQL managed instance across subscription?

Comment: Not sure, the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#services-that-can-be-moved) does not say it can be moved or cannot. I have an idea, you could navigate to your sql managed instance in the portal, check if there is an `Move` option, like https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI2UH.png. In general, if it can be moved, it will have the option.

Comment: @Sourav Karmakar, as this is not documented anywhere, it's good to know information from the Product Team.

To get information from product team,  I would request you to provide the feedback here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-resource-limits#feedback

Comment: Yeah, I gave a feedback.

Comment: On the SQL managed instance Overview, you can change the Subscription. Maybe you can try it. Screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/msp00.png

Comment: @LeonYue , It does not help. Getting some error regarding the virtual cluster to which the SQL MI belongs. It says Virtual cluster doesn't support move or updating references after move.

Comment: @SouravKarmakar I find the answer, please see my update.

Answer (score -1):

Azure SQL managed instance supports the move operation: move to another resource group or another subscription. You can get this from this document: [Move operation support for resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/move-support-resources#microsoftsql).
[image]

If you want to move the managed instance subscription, you need to operate on the resource group overview. Choose all the resource about managed instance.
[image]

For more details, please see this Azure tutorial: [Move resources to new resource group or subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#move-resources):

**Summary:**

This article shows you how to move Azure resources to either another Azure subscription or another resource group under the same subscription. You can use the Azure portal, Azure PowerShell, Azure CLI, or the REST API to move resources.

Both the source group and the target group are locked during the move operation. Write and delete operations are blocked on the resource groups until the move completes. This lock means you can't add, update, or delete resources in the resource groups, but it doesn't mean the resources are frozen. For example, if you move a SQL Server and its database to a new resource group, an application that uses the database experiences no downtime. It can still read and write to the database.

Moving a resource only moves it to a new resource group. The move operation can't change the location of the resource. The new resource group may have a different location, but that doesn't change the location of the resource.

It also gives you many examples about how to move resource group or subscription:

1. [By using Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#by-using-azure-portal).
2. [By using Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#by-using-azure-powershell).
3. [By using Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#by-using-azure-cli).
4. [By using REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#by-using-rest-api).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your information, but when I tried to move the Manage Instance along with dependent resources I got some error like this - 
"Cannot move resource /subscriptions/*******************/resourceGroups/RG-SK-SQL-MI/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VNet_SqlMI since it references resource /subscriptions/*********************/resourceGroups/RG-SK-SQL-MI/providers/Microsoft.Sql/virtualClusters/VirtualCluster**************a0?api-version=2015-05-01-preview, which does not support move or updating references after the move."
How to over come this problem ?

Comment: Is it possible to stop a virtualNetwork ? If so, how ?

Comment: @SouravKarmakar Sorry I said it wrong. According the error message, how about update the VirtualCluster ? See this link [Virtual Clusters - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/virtualclusters/update). If the error still happens, I suggest you call the [Azure Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#when-to-call-azure-support)  when move classic resources but are having trouble with the limitations.